# Finding local and global minimisers of an objective function.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am studying the field of optimisation and have came across the following question concerning local minimisers and I demonstrate my work below I am confused with if the minimisers I have found are correct.

**Question**
Consider the objective function: $$f(x,y) = 2x^{3} + xy^{2} + 5x^{2} + y^2.$$

Find the points which satisfy the first-order necessary conditions for local extremisers. Which of these points are local minimisers and maximisers, and does f(x,y) have any global minimisers?

**My attempt**

By computing the partial derivatives and setting the results equal to 0:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) =\ 6x^{2} + y^{2} + 10x =0
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) =\ 2xy + 2y = 0
$$

The points which I have found are:

x1 = [0,0]

x2=[-5/3 , 0]

x3  = [-1, 2]

x4 = [-1, -2]

To try and find the minimisers I have done:

$$H = \left[\begin{array}{cc}{12x+10} & {2y}\\ {2y} & {2x+2}\end{array}\right]$$
$$

Evaluating the points:

x1, has two eigenvalues which are both 0 - this is therefore a saddle point.

x2, has eigenvalues of -4/3 and -10, these values are real and negative, this is therefore a local maximiser.

x3, has eigenvalues: -1+-sqrt(17), there is one eigenvalue which is negative and one which is positive. This is therefore a saddle point.

x4, has the same eigenvalues as x3 and so I come to the same conclusion.

Therefore I have found that x2 = [-5/3, 0] is a global maximiser and there are no global minimisers.

In finding any global minimisers I consider that I need to show that the local extremisers I need to find the values which are less than or equal to f(x,y) although I don't really know what to do at this stage.

Thank you for any assistance, I am grateful for any help.

-S

Comment: Just so you know, you can put an expression between single \$ signs to get MathJax inline. For example, `$x^y$` produces $x^y$.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will bare this in mind in future :)

Comment: It is $$-\infty<f(x,y)$$

Comment: I do not understand, could please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your partial derivatives, your critical points, and your Hessian.

You say that, at $x_1$, $H$ has $0$ as both its eigenvalues (I agree), but this does not imply that $x_1$ is a saddle point. The second derivative test has failed in this case, and further study is required to determine the nature of the critical point. As it turns out, it's a local minimum, but it takes a bit more work to prove. Note that
$$\operatorname{det} H = (12x + 10)(2x + 2) - 4y^2.$$
For $(x, y)$ close, but not equal to $0$, note that this determinant is going to be strictly positive (the whole expression tends to $20$ as $(x, y) \to 0$) and $(12x + 10)(2x + 2) > 0$, again for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$. This tells us that $H$ is positive semidefinite on a neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$, which implies that $f$ is convex on this neighbourhood, and so $(0, 0)$ must be a local minimum.

I agree with the other eigenvalue computations and their conclusions.

As for the conclusions about global extrema, I disagree that $(-5/3, 0)$ is a global maximiser. I don't really understand how you did get to this conclusion, but it's not right. If you consider $f(x, y)$ along the line $y = 0$, you get
$$f(x, 0) = 2x^3 + 5x^2,$$
which is a cubic function in $x$. As $x \to \infty$, $f(x, 0) \to \infty$ and as $x \to -\infty$, $f(x, 0) \to -\infty$. Therefore, the values in the range of $f$ become as large and positive as you like, and also become as large and negative as you like, proving that none of the extrema are global.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)